# Variety and algebraic curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, proof-verification

I am attempting the following problem from Artin:

> Every variety in $\mathbb{C^2}$ is the union of finitely many points and algebraic curves.

I think the proof is trivial (unless I am missing something).

My attempt: We know a variety is just a set of common zeroes of finite number of polynomials. Geometrically we interpret this as drawing all the polynomials we have and see where they intersect (and union of all these points will be a variety). This union is finite as there are  finite number of polynomials and so we are done!

So, in this proof where did we need any union of algebraic curves?

Comment: "This union is finite". Why? What do you get if you take the equation $z_1=0$ in $\mathbf C^2$ with coordinates $(z_1,z_2)$?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Both $z_1$ and $z_2$ would have to be 0. My reasoning was by Bezout's theorem the solution set of each polynomial is finite. So, their intersection is too. But the points in the intersection can be seen as union of ("special") points in complex plane and thus they have to be finite

Comment: Why would $z_2$ have to be zero? And why is the solution set of each polynomial finite? (Indeed, it is not; that was what my previous comment was getting at.)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Aha! so thats where we need the fact about algebraic curves